# Debian Bash Associative Array Self (Internal) Referencing

Tags: bash, debian, array

I'm attempting to contruct an associative array where key-value pairs within the array, reference other key-value pairs in the same array, using Debian Gnu-Linux 12.4, 22.12.3 and Bash 5.2.15.

Example,

```
declare -A test=(
    [0]=0
    [1]=1
    [2]=2
    [3]=$((test[1]+test[2]))
    [4]="${test[1]} ${test[2]}"
)
```

When I execute the following echo statements in Konsole,

```
echo "${test[1]}"
echo "${test[2]}"
echo "${test[3]}"
echo "${test[4]}"
```

I sometimes get this result,

```
1
2
0
```

and sometimes I get what I intended

```
1
2
3
1 2
```

Because of this inconsistency (which could be solely on my doing), I have a few questions.

1. Can this be done?
2. If yes, is there a proper way of doing this?

Also, I can't find a consistent method for replicating the two different results, either will happen no matter what or how.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in the way that you're trying to do, because **variable references are not stored** within the array – rather, they are immediately evaluated as part of the 'string literal' expression – so at the time the reference is evaluated, *the assignment to `test` hasn't been done yet.* (The same as in many other programming languages!)

(Despite the similarity in syntax, only the `test=…` or `test[3]=…` is an actual variable assignment, but the `( [0]=… )` is not – Bash's array key/value syntax merely mimics the real `test[3]=…` assignment syntax, but in other languages the exact same concept would usually look like `test = { "0": 1234 }` or similar.)

You will need multiple assignments to do it correctly:

```
declare -A test=(
    [0]=0
    [1]=1
    [2]=2
)

test[3]=$(( test[1] + test[2] ))

test[4]="${test[1]} ${test[2]}"

test+=(
    [5]="${test[3]} and ${test[4]}"
    [6]="${test[4]} but not yet ${test[5]}"
)
```

Each of the four operations in the above example is a single assignment; first all variable references and other `$`-expansions are processed, then the value of `test` is updated.

> Also, I can't find a consistent method for replicating the two different results, either will happen no matter what or how.

If you get a result from the expansion in your example, it is using the values from a *previous* assignment. Put a `declare -p test` before (and after) the assignment to see what values are stored.

To ensure consistency in your experiments, do `unset test` before each attempt.

Comment: Thank you very much u1686_grawity, works a treat consistantly, and explained quite well why my tests were inconsistent.